# Infinite Scroll and loading div

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I use this plugin

```
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
```

I need to place a loading div to my load button.

```
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/trigger.html
```

I didn't find any doc at plugin's site how to do that. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
 $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector: '#nav-pagination-load-more',
                nextSelector: '#nav-pagination-load-more .next',
                itemSelector: '.hentry',
                loading: {
                    selector: '#load-more',
                    finishedMsg: 'No more posts to load.',
                    img: 'http://cdn.moozpaper.com/lucidpress/wp-content/themes/lucidpress/images/loading_small.gif',
                    msgText: ''
                }
            },
```